# Certificate error was raised when installing oracledb in Electron app

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, node-gyp

I am running Windows 7 with oracledb v1.10.0, electron-prebuilt v1.2.2, electron-rebuild v1.1.5, node v0.12.7, and npm v2.11.3. When I execute `node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild -f -w oracledb`, I receive the following error:

```
gyp ERR! stack Error: certificate not trusted
gyp ERR! stack     at Error (native)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:929:36)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:104:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:460:8)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "H:\\electron-quick-start\\node_modules\\electron-rebuild\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node
-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "install" "--target=1.2.7" "--arch=x64" "--dist-url=https://gh-contractor-zcbenz.s3.amazonaws.co
m/atom-shell/dist"
gyp ERR! cwd H:\electron-quick-start
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

How can I get this command to successfully execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificate error I was getting was due to being behind a corporate firewall under Windows. To solve that, I removed the s from https so the dist-url value became http://gh-contractor-zcbenz.s3.amazonaws.com/atom-shell/dist. The other error I was getting was (as mentioned by @Thennarasan) "Module did not self-register" and to solve that I called the following commands and it worked:

```
PS H:\electron-app> cd node_modules\oracledb
PS H:\electron-app\node_modules\oracledb> node-gyp rebuild --target=1.2.8 --arch=x64 --target_platform=win --dist-url=http://gh-contractor-zcbenz.s3.amazonaws.com/atom-shell/dist --msvs_version=2013
PS H:\electron-app> cd ..\..
```

I got help from this Github issue https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1529.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be Module did not self register. On Windows, 'node' is actually a batch file that calls iojs and native modules don't like that. You will need to copy your iojs executable to 'node' as well to satisfy native modules.

Now, I am unclear about exactly what your attempting. But if you would like to utilize a native module from within Electron, you will need to build your native code against the Electron includes/header, not those of iojs. You can take a look at this for an example of the command syntax:

```
node-gyp rebuild --target=0.22.3 --arch=ia32 --target_platform=win --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell
```

Comment: I'm trying to connect to Oracle database through the Electron app I'm building. I'm currently using oracledb (https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb) but I'm also open to other options.

Comment: Can you try run without https `http://gh-contractor-zcbenz.s3.amazonaws.co
m/atom-shell/dist`

Comment: How do I set the dist-url? Please advise.

Comment: For that you have to modify the .npmrc file.

Comment: @Thennarasan Did you mean to have "call" in the command you pasted?

Comment: Kindly refer this [link](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules.md)

Comment: I installed electron-rebuild using this command: "npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild" and it installed with no errors but then when I call this command ".\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd" I get the same error as above. I modified the .npmrc file and added all dependencies you mentioned but when I call the command it runs as if nothing changed.

Comment: @Thennarasan where exactly does npm read target, arch, dist-url from?